# Is there a way to format a conversation in markdown?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I'm writing a document in markdown, intended to be formatted by Pandoc. I'd like to have a conversation between two or more people in that document, where each sentence gets prefixed by a dash, or at least gets on its own line without causing a new paragraph indent or extra lineskip; is there a standard way of marking this up?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: "- a\n- b\n- c" would give `<ul><li>a<li>...</ul>` whereas "- a\n\n- b\\n- c" would give paragraphs: `<ul><li><p>a</p><li>...</ul>`.

Comment: How would you do that in HTML? I suspect the answer to that is the answer for Markdown. As a reminder, Markdown only supports a subset of HTML, so your options are limited.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 standard [mentions conversations](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#conversations) and suggests to just use normal `<p>` elements for each person. It seems that the best method is therefor to use empty lines between each person, and to use something like a fenced div to mark the conversation:

```
These two causes made him answer in a very low and hesitating voice;
whereupon a gentleman in a white waistcoat said he was a fool. Which
was a capital way of raising his spirits, and putting him quite at
his ease.

::: {.conversation}
'Boy,' said the gentleman in the high chair, 'listen to me.
You know you're an orphan, I suppose?'

'What's that, sir?' inquired poor Oliver.

'The boy _is_ a fool---I thought he was,' said the gentleman in the
white waistcoat.
:::
```

One can then use CSS to indent the code and reduce spacing as desired. A [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) could be used to adjust output when targeting other formats, like PDF via LaTeX.